# Thumbnail with the like button in my website

Tags: web, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I used the iframe to add the like button to my website

and after read many questions/answer related with my issue I add to the HEAD:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
<meta property="og:title" content="EL SUR TAMBIEN ES AMERICA"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://elsuresamerica.weebly.COM/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

I debugged it and get:

"More Than One OG URL Specified:
Object at URL (my web site) of type 'website' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: (my web site), (my web site)"

I don't understand what that means. I am not a developer, just a writer and I'm getting crazy with this. Please I need help to show a thumbnail in FB when the like button is clicked.
Thanks!

Comment: _“I don't understand what that means.”_ – Why not? _“More Than One OG URL Specified”_ is pretty plain and simple English, isn’t it? Look at the source code of your page, http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://elsuresamerica.weebly.com/ – several of the meta tags are appearing there twice.

Comment: I did not understand because in the Weebly HTML editor (the one I have been able to find) I did not see those meta tags, just the meta tags I added. I just don't know how to access to the whole HTML to modify it. I just added what I saw here in this forum, in other answers to questions like mine. If you can kindly tell me how to access to the HTML I really would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the original code, I'd first see if it is because the 1st meta tag is not closed ;-) Try adding /> to the end of the 1st line

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake when I copied it. The original is closed.